# Date format with onchange

Tags: javascript

I have many difficulties in doing this kind of formatting in the field. I have a form field:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">        
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
        {{Form::label('data', 'Data')}}
    </div>         
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">            
        {{Form::date('data', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>     
</div>
```

The intention is to make this field be in the following format, 
when a person enters 2 numbers the field automatically places a " / " forming the following type " 2 / 2 / 4 " insofar as the person is typing. However there is a detail, field allows the use of the backspace key but this will not compromise the automatic use of " / ".

I tried to do as the other topics but did not have success...

Comment: You should consider using an input mask plugin instead of doing this by hand IMO.

Comment: What libs are you using? It seems like you are using a mustache template

Comment: Fausto, Thanks, Saudades, hahaha............Casey, I think I understand what you said , I will research the matter........Filipe, i use --> " bootstrap.min.css ", " bootstrap-theme.min.css ", " jquery-1.12.0.min.js ", " bootstrap.min.js " and " font-awesome.min.css ",  I think that's it.

Comment: Note that there is a Portuguese version of Stack Overflow here: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @LincolnBinda Is my answe useul?

Comment: Sorry, not see before, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to this work. Check text format using `match()`.

```js
var lastValue = $("input").val();
$("input").on("keydown keyup change", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.match(/^[0-9]*[\/]?[0-9]*[\/]?[0-9]*$/g))
        lastValue = value;
    else
        $(this).val(lastValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```